# How to cascade update to child entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, design-patterns, persistence

I have three entities: Credentials, User and Admin. Both User and Admin entities have a field credentials, which is related to Credentials entity using OneToOne annotation.

When updating an existing User or Admin entry, through entityManager.merge, I am getting duplicated key over Credentials.login column, which has unique constraint.

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Credentials {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, length=50)
    private String login;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=50)
    private String password;

    /*********************************************
    *  getters and setters here
    **********************************************/
}

@Entity
@Table
public class User{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    /*********************************************
    *  Specific user columns here
    **********************************************/

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name = "idCredentials")
    private Credentials credentials;

    /*********************************************
    *  getters and setters here
    **********************************************/
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Admin{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    /*********************************************
    *  Specific admin columns here
    **********************************************/

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name = "idCredentials")
    private Credentials credentials;

    /*********************************************
    *  getters and setters here
    **********************************************/
}
```

I expect to have user and user.credentials updated in respective database tables after calling entityManager.merge(user), but I am getting the error "Duplicate entry 'loginname' for key 'login_UNIQUE. The same happens with Admin entity.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you may be getting this error is due to the fact that `merge` copies the contents of a detached entity into a managed entity. So, if you are passing as an argument to `merge` a `User` or `Admin` entity (from now on referred as `PERSON`) that contains a **detached** copy of a `Credentials` entity persisted in the DB; then you will definitely be getting this problem. The reason for this is:

1. `merge` will copy the entire state of the `PERSON` entity argument into the corresponding **context managed** `PERSON` entity.
2. This copy will include the `Credentials` entity inside the `PERSON` argument.
3. Since the `Credentials` entity was detached, the persistence manager will assume this entity corresponds to an entity not persisted yet.
4. The persistence context, when flushing the session, will save the **merged** `Credentials` using an `INSERT` (persist the new `Credentials`) rather than an `UPDATE`.
5. The `INSERT` will trigger the duplicate constrain violation on the `login` field you are getting, because the original `Credentials` record exist with the `login` value being used in the `INSERT`.

**EDIT: (How to merge)**

If you are not updating the `Credentials` in `PERSON`, then when merging in your `PERSON_DAO`, you could:

1. Temporarily remove `Credentials` from `PERSON` (`null`) before merging.
2. Merge `PERSON`.
3. Add the original `Credentials` back to your **newly merged** `PERSON`

Since I have no access to your `DAO` code, here is a pseudo code of the previous:

```
    public PERSON mergeSafely(PERSON person) {
        Credentials originalCredentials = person.getCredentials();
        person.setCredentials(null);
        person = em.merge(person);
        person.setCredentials(originalCredentials);
        return person;
    }
```

In case you want to merge also the `Credentials`, then you should (for cleanness sake) use the `service` layer above the `dao` layer. A pseudo code of a utility method to accomplish this in that layer would look like:

```
    public PERSON mergeCompletely(PERSON person) {
        Credentials mergedCredentials = credentialsDAO.merge(person.getCredentials());
        person.setCredentials(mergedCredentials);
        person = personDAO.merge(person);
        return person;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank your for the clarification @Marco R. You was right indeed. I added the call `user.setCredentials(entityManager.merge(user.getCredentials()))` to get user.credentials managed just before call `entityManager.merge(user)` and it fixed the problem.

However I did not like this solution since it mixes a call to CredentialsDAO inside UserDAO. Is there a more elegant way to solve the problem? I mean, is there a way to save both user and its credentials at one shot?

Comment: I just added an answer to the question in your comment as an edit in my original answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying again @Marco R. My person.credentials also have data to be updated, so I believe `person.setCredentials(null);` would cause credentials not to be updated along with person.

Comment: I already edited the answer to include the latest consideration.